# I import and merge multiple Excel files together but lose the information of the excel file name in R

Tags: r, import

I import and merge multiple Excel files together and more specifically, I only need  sheet 2 of each excel file to be imported and then merged together in a big dataframe. All excel files contain same variables so this is the easy part.

file_list <- dir(path, pattern = ".xls")

df<- lapply(file_list, read_excel, sheet=2)

When I do this however, I want to also add an extra column and paste the original excel file name for each row, so I will not lose the source file for each entry.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```r
df <- lapply(file_list, function(f_name) {
  f <- read_excel(f_name, sheet=2)
  cbind(f, file_name=f_name)  # add file name as a new column
})

df <- do.call(rbind, df)
```